# Display the first and second columns of a SQL table

Tags: java

I have a table of two SQL columns, (name and address).

I want show the first and second data of the second column.

I am using this code

```
while (res.next()){
 System.out.print(res.getString(2))
}
```

But it gives me the all of second column 
How can i show the first and second data

Comment: `res.getString(1)` will get you the first column value?

Comment: yes all of values abut me i want show data1 and data2

Comment: @cisco.nat Do you mean rows?

Answer (score 1):

The index that you see in `getString` method is the column index. So:

```
while (res.next()){
    System.out.print(res.getString(1) + " " + res.getString(2));
}
```

Comment: no this it will give me the firet data of the first column look like i have table of 2 columns name and age so in name i have 2 names ans in age i have 2 ages i want display the first age

Comment: Then just add `break;` after the `print`

Answer (score 0):

I assume you mean that you only want the first two rows?

Just count how many rows you've output, and end the loop early.  By using a while .. next loop as your sample code, you avoid problems if the `ResultSet` has only zero or one rows.

```
int rowsOutput = 0;
while( res.next()) {
    System.out.println(res.getString(2));
    rowsOutput ++;
    if( rowsOutput >= 2) {
        break;
    }
}
```

Or, add a `LIMIT` clause to your SQL to only select the first two rows.

Comment: because i want write every one in a function the first and the second so how can i do that this code it display me the 2 rows

Comment: i want just diplay data of address i want choice the index 1 and 2 because i will use every one in function

Comment: i have on row "address" 2 addresses : 127.3.2.3 and 124.2.4.4 so i want in 2 functions use one address: Config("127.3.2.3");Config1("124.2.4.4") so how do this with getString

Answer (score 0):

> But it gives me the all of second column How can i show the first and
>   second data

It's because you created loop `->` while there is any data, print it.

So if you want to print only first two rows, you need to create for example some helping variable e.q.

```
int index = 0;
while (res.next() && index < 2) {
   System.out.print(res.getString("name"));
   System.out.print(res.getString("address"));
   index++;
}
```

**Note:** I recommend you to use column names instead of indexes. In this way you'll avoid problems with incorrect indexing (usual mistakes).

Comment: No if i do System.out.print(res.getString(1)) it will give me the column one and i don't want dispaly the data of column one i want display column 2 And me who must choice the index of which row

Comment: i have on row "address" 2 addresses : 127.3.2.3 and 124.2.4.4 so i want in 2 functions use one address: Config("127.3.2.3");Config1("124.2.4.4") so how do this with getString

Comment: @cisco.nat you have in one column both addresses?